# New web application or customization of existing openstack horizon

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I am exploring different options to for using openstack horizon.

1. Use existing horizon app and add new dashboard and apps to it
2. Start web application from scratch and use openstack APIs and Reactjs for frontend.

Which option shall we select and if we go with option 2 then is there any way we can use existing horizon app modules in our application? I am also open for any other option which you guys can suggest to explore.

Note: I am newbie at it so please let me know how i can improvise also.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it depends if you want the user interface to be part of your OpenStack / Horizon dashboard or now.

If you do, then there is only one choice.  Build it as Horizon plugin. End of story.

If you don't, then you need to make a judgment as to whether using Horizon as a framework for your user interface is going to be advantageous or not.

- On the plus side, Horizon provides lot of infrastructure for implementing plugins, a panel structure, modal dialogs and so on.  It also has some nice stuff for integrating Openstack auth into Django.
- On the minus side, Horizon is complicated and not well documented.  The learning curve is significant.  You will also need to do some work to remove or disable panels, etc that Horizon provides by default.  You may find that aspects of the Horizon are hard to modify ... if they are not suitable for your UI design.

Finally, you need to consider the long-term maintainability of an (in effect) fork of the Horizon codebase.  What happens when (say) Django 1.x is end-of-life and you are stuck with a version of Horizon that has diverged from mainline Horizon.

My gut feeling (based on experience with Horizon plugins) is that you would probably be better off NOT using Horizon in this case.  Build it from scratch using Django or Reactjs or something else.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for insight, I am also thinking on going with new application, Can you guide to any useful resources that I can use as start point for intergrating Openstack APIs apart from documentation , Thanks

Comment: Look at the OpenStack SDK library.  There are lots of examples of this and of the use of the service-specific client libraries.